# Learn to multiply using Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have written a program that learns to add,

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from random import randint
reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
x=[[randint(0,100),randint(0,100)] for i in range(1000)]
Y=[i[0]+i[1] for i in x]
reg.fit(x, Y)
print(reg.pred([[56, 23]])
# OUTPUT : 79
```

Please help me with this program if i want it to do multiplication, i get very low accuracy.

Please make as less changes as possible to the program as i am a newbie.

!!Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I would say the accuracy with Addition isn't that great too.

Comment: You are right i just miss typed it(its reverse actually).

Comment: Actually you should make sure that you don't test on training data. So define a dataset X and split it in training and testing data and make sure they are disjoint

Comment: @pythonic833 The methodology of performance evaluation is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have multiple solutions to your problem.
To achieve 0 error, you need to learn a model that can learn this kind of complexity. You probably want to use simple models like Linear Regression, and therefore, you should expand your data using *polynomial features*. See `sklearn.processing.PolynomialFeatures` [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html).

Alternative solutions can involve more complicated models such as *Neural Networks*. You can simply use multi-layer network with 2-3 hidden layers, and **linear** output layer so that the output will be unbounded. This method will be less preferred for this kind of problem since it is more complex and not guaranteed to perform the best on your problem.

**Note**:
If you do choose to try a network for this simple problem, make sure to use a *Mean loss*.

**Example**:

First, lets load some tools.
We will use linear regression and a pre-processing toolkit by scikit-learn.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import preprocessing
from random import randint
import numpy as np
```

**Addition problem**

```
# Lets generate some random data
x=[[randint(0,100),randint(0,100)] for i in range(1000)]

# and compute the deterministic addition function
Y=[i[0]+i[1] for i in x]
```

Since `x+y` is a linear combination of `x` and `y`,
we do not need to do any feature extraction on our data.
Minimization objective in linear regression is `np.sum((x * w -Y) ** 2)`
where we minimize over w.
Optimal parameters for this model are `[1, 1]`.

```
# First, we create an instance of the regressor
reg_add=linear_model.LinearRegression()

# then, fit it to the data
reg_add.fit(x, Y)

# and finally, test it on some sample
sample = [[56, 23]]
print('Addition: X={}, Y_hat={}'.format(sample,reg_add.predict(sample)))
```

Output:

```
Addition: X=[[56, 23]], Y_hat=[79.]
```

**Multiplication problem**

```
# Again, lets generate some random data
x=[[randint(0,100),randint(0,100)] for i in range(1000)]

# And compute the multiplication of all coordinates for each sample
Y=np.array([i[0]*i[1] for i in x])
```

Now, a simple linear regressor cannot fit accurately to the data,
since `x[0]*x[1]` is **not** a linear combination of elements in the sample.
However, if we choose polynomial feature extraction, we can.
Polynomial features are all polynomial combinations of the coordinates up the a defined degree, including degree `0`.

```
# Lets create an instance of the processor, using polynomial features of degree=2
pp = preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures(2)

# transform the original data
x2 = pp.fit_transform(x)

# Then, create a linear regressor,
reg_mult=linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Fit it to the processed data and the results
reg_mult.fit(x2, Y)

# and test it on a new example.
sample = [[2, 4]]
print('Multiplication: X={}, Y_hat={}'.format(sample,reg_mult.predict(pp.transform(sample))))
```

Output:

```
Multiplication: X=[[2, 4]], Y_hat=[8.]
```

Comment: Mamamiya you are brilliant

Comment: What should i do for division!
Explanation along with SRC will be helpful.

Comment: Added more notes for your convenience :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but can you help me on division problem.

Comment: For division you'll need more complicated model or to extract more meaningful features. For instance, you can extract the features `1/x` first, and then use the polynomial feature extraction, and then use the linear regressor. **Note that model prior knowledge is and model construction is NOT machine learning!**. In a case of exploring data and trying to learn targets, we cannot do the above. It would simply be a guess, which is ok if you start with exploration and do it because you visualize the data and guess or so. **EDIT**: Forgot to point out again, there are many other models you can use

Comment: Brilliant, I will apply this tonight! & let you know what happens!

Comment: As the graph for 1/x is not a straight line so I cannot use linear regression,
 then what should I use!

Comment: Neural_network helps me now but i not getting 100% accuracy for finding 1/x.

If you have any solutions plz share!!

Comment: I have done it exactly as you said plz help me with accuracy!  

 please visit my previous post

Comment: Hi, I answered the division problem - use the answer as feature / train a neural network with linear outputs if you want to do that with deep learning. Unfortunately, there is no real question you are asking, you simply need to sit and learn and try various ML models until you succeed. I will be glad to help if you have a real question according to the rules. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

friend! In your problem statement the linear model with y = Ax is set by you, and model.fit() just tells you the obvious coefficients i.e.
i[0]+i[1] =y is [1 1]*dot_product*[i0 i1]

if you still want to fit in this manner some nonlinear functions(or highly nonlinear data) you should choose an appropriate interval where your model fits reasonably well
or(and) choose an appropriate basis (polynomial, or generate [1, 1/x] series, or harmonics or any other) and then find a nearly the best linear combination of those basis components(features) i.e. linear_model.fit()